# Managing Database Records separately with different UserTypes(Roles)

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic

I am asking a logical help currently. I have few roles in database, they are in hierarchical order. When the user with lowest role deletes the record it should not be deleted for the user with the role above.

How should I create my database table, and how can I create such system?

I have not defined records on purpose. Records can be of any table. Whenever a user logs in to the system, and deletes some records, those records must still be visible by the user with higher

Comment: What record are you talking about?  How does this record relate to user roles?

Answer (score 0):

You have given us very little to go off of, but at a high level I think a structure like this would work:

```
Users
----------
UserId
RoleId
UserName


UserRecords
-----------
UserId
RecordId

Records
-----------
RecordId
SomeInfo
```

When a user "deletes" a record you should just remove the corresponding entry in the UserRecords table.  This will prevent one user from deleting records for other users.  They would only be able to delete their relationship to that record.

Comment: Sorry, for being unclear, but I have not defined records on purpose. Records can be of any table. Whenever a user logs in to the system, and deletes some records, those records must still be visible by the user with higher roles.